# How to Filter Podcasts from Spotify Steaming Data

Tags: python, json, spotify

I recently pulled my Spotify streaming data through the "Download your data" option they give users. I'm just using it to play around in Python with some data analysis-related libraries, letting my friends see their streaming trends, things like that, and I want to figure out if there's a way to filter out podcasts from the data. In theory it sounds easy, but unfortunately the data is pretty limited. Spotify sends the data in the form of JSON files, and each entry only has 4 attributes. Here's an example of a song entry and a podcast entry to show what I mean:

```
{
"endTime" : "2021-01-21 00:36",
"artistName" : "Gojira",
"trackName" : "OROBORUS",
"msPlayed" : 321786
},
{
"endTime" : "2021-04-17 15:45",
"artistName" : "Androids & Aliens",
"trackName" : "Episode 40 - Baby, It's Mold Outside",
"msPlayed" : 1463731
}
```

So there's no particularly solid way to distinguish between them. I figured the best ways forward would be either filtering out long stream times or somehow checking the artist name. The issue with stream time is that I and many people I know listen to things like progressive metal where one song can run upwards of 20 minutes, and some tracks even reach the hour mark, so it would be very difficult to draw that line. I looked into the name matching, but I could not find any sort of list of podcasts on Spotify, though I did find out there are supposedly 3.2 million of them on there so that's not terribly encouraging.

So at this point I'm effectively back to the drawing board and not really sure where to go. Anyone else ever mess around with this stuff? If so, I'm open to any ideas. Thanks

Comment: If you can't get help from here then maybe the [official Spotify for Developers board](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/bd-p/Spotify_Developer) would have more info.

Comment: The docs state that podcasts list the episode, so for the example data you posted you could filter on 'episode' in '"trackName" : "Episode 40 - Baby, It's Mold Outside",'

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Wow yeah I totally missed that. I feel like the number of songs with "Episode" in their name is negligible enough that this could work. I'll make sure to include the space and hyphen to avoid as many edge cases as possible

Comment: Good to hear. Happy to help.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman So unfortunately, the track name always has an episode number, but it doesn't always say episode. I have some in my data that are "Ep. ###: " and some that are "PodcastName ###: " format so I don't think it's consistent enough

Comment: Interesting. I'm surprised the JSON objects don't contain the media type.

Comment: I am too, I honestly expected a lot more information than they gave